# javascruipt menu hover active

Tags: javascript, menu

am having a menu with five elements all under div's with same class.
onclick of a selected menu ( div) i want to make the font-weight of selected to bold.
for that i used .classname a:active{font-weight:Bold}.

this will make menu -item bold on active,but only on click, but it gets again normal when  mouse click event ends.

But i need to make the menu-item bold until the user clicks on another menu-item.

howz it possible.
menu structre.

```
<div class="coolmenu">
 <a>menu1</a>
</div> <div class="coolmenu">
 <a>menu2</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On click first you have to set font-weight to normal for all menu elements and then set bold only for clicked one, something like this:

```
$('.coolmenu a').click( function(){
 $('.coolmenu a').css('font-weight','normal');
 $(this).css('font-weight','bold');
});
```

Maybe it will better if you use `addClass` instead `css`, it will give you more flexibility.

Comment: You should add a note on using jQuery ;-)